# Using char ** as C# DLLImport Parameter

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling, dllimport

I am trying to use the following function from my .NET application...

```
int mysql_library_init(int argc, char **argv, char **groups)
```

Where the *argv* and *groups* params are passed the following...

```
static char *server_args[] = {
  "this_program",       /* this string is not used */
  "--datadir=.",
  "--key_buffer_size=32M"
};
static char *server_groups[] = {
  "embedded",
  "server",
  "this_program_SERVER",
  (char *)NULL
};
```

How can I do this within C#?

Comment: Please check this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/marshalarrayofstrings.aspx - check the helper method under section: "Building the Argument for the Call". Very usefull!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the arguments as string[].

Pinvoking the MySql native interface is painful and unnecessary.  Use its [.NET data provider](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/).

Comment: I am trying to setup the embedded MySQL server, will those work?

Comment: I don't know.  Give them a call, that's how these guys make a living.  As long as it is embedded, why do you care about the implementation?  SqlLite and SQL Compact have excellent .NET wrappers.